# Onvif RTSP over HTTP

Tags: streaming, rtsp, onvif

I`m trying to make an IP Camera to work with the onvif specification. (I try to develop the services on the camera, the server)

The Camera does only support rtsp over http and I have no idea how to get this working with e.g. the Onvif test tool.

I have the rtsp stream uri but when I send it to the client it gives me a describe error. what do I have to send to the Client so it knows that it is rtsp over http?

Answer (score 0):

You could act as a proxy between the RTSP client and the camera - direct all the RTSP requests to the POST channel of the RTSP over HTTP connection and write everything you receive in the GET connection back to the client.